# How to input dd-mm-yyyy h:m:s values in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 with a column `PeriodEndDate` with should take values in the format

```
 20-07-2014 00:00:00
```

e.g.

```
 dd-mm-yyyy h:m:s
```

Please help.

Thanks!
Sonia

Comment: Help with what?  What issue are you having doing what you want?  As a side note - `DateTime` does not _have_ a format.  You only specify a format when you _display_ it.

Answer (score 1):

datetime is your friend.

```
create table TABLE1 (
ID_WS_AUDIT_MSG      bigint               identity,
LOGGED_USER          nvarchar(40)         not null,
WS_NAME              varchar(256)         null,
EVENT_TIME           datetime             null
```

....

Comment: For SQL Server **2008 and newer**, I would recommend using `DATETIME2(n)` - first of all, it's more precise (down to 100ns, if needed), secondly you can choose your precision, and thirdly, it supports a much broader date range (from 1/1/0001 to 31/12/9999), and lastly, it's a lot less finicky about converting dates in string representations than `DATETIME` ever was...

Comment: @marc_s I would only use `DATETIME2` if you actually *need* the precision and range. It's the same reason you don't just use `BIGINT` for every integer. If you don't care about subsecond accuracy or dates before 1800 (accepting also that calendars prior to this often had new years beginning in *March or April*) then you're just wasting space and processing on storing data you do not need.

Comment: @BaconBits: on the contrary! I would **always** use `DATETIME2` over `DATETIME` - you're actually using ***less*** space, and you have less hassle converting strings to `DATETIME2(n)`, and you don't have that artificial, unintuitive break in the date range in 1753...